# How to close msgBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this implementation:

[example page for the script I am using](http://dotctor.github.io/jQuery.msgBox/)

of jquery msgbox and I am really puzzled by how to call a close for the messagebox in javascript. Tried various things, but I cant seem to hit the correct hide() function, as it doesnt remove the opaque background it created. Manually click buttons work ok...

As a test, I would simply want to hide the message on

```
$.msgBox({
title:"Hello",
content:"Hello World!"
    afterShow: function () {
      //close it when reach this
    },
});
```

I am puzzled by the notation itself `$.msgBox` - how do I access this object functions from jQuery?

Comment: I have seen the code. And think there is no beautiful way. But you may call $("input.msgButton").click() for this purpose.

Comment: Or trigger a click on the background, `$('.msgBoxBackGround').click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.msgBox({
title:"Hello",
content:"Hello World!"
    afterShow: function () {
      //close it when reach this
      $(".msgButton").trigger('click');
    },
});
```

use .trigger() to close the dialog.

Comment: and if there is no button? what then? I want a clean solution $(..).hide()

Comment: $('.msgBoxBackGround').trigger('click');

Comment: I analysed the code of that plugin, No such option was gived. So you have to customize for your need.

Comment: I used a little different approach, but since you bothered to answer, I accept your answer ;)